# SSH: can't connect via SSH, but 'Authentication succeeded'

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, ssh

I have a VPS with Ubuntu 16.04 64bit with SSH on it. For the last half a year it works great (I can log in with `root`+password or with my user `pavlovdog` with `id_rsa` key). But today, I can't log in at all - verbose tells me that `Authentication succeeded` and nothing happens. I can't even close process with `ctrl+c` - so I need to close terminal.

I've tried to:

- Restart VPS from VPS-provider panel (didn't help)
- `systemctl reload sshd` (didn't help. BTW I can log in as `root` from another laptop - seems that the problem is on my side)
- Log in using VPN (didn't help)

Here's a trace from `ssh pavlovdog@IP -v` (I have replaced real IP address with `IP` placeholder, but I can reveal it if necessary). Pretty same trace shown while logging with `root`:

```
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/pavlovdog/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to IP [IP] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/pavlovdog/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/pavlovdog/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/pavlovdog/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/pavlovdog/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/pavlovdog/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/pavlovdog/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/pavlovdog/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/pavlovdog/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to IP:22 as 'pavlovdog'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:WYLT9dlZYLhu7k4JVLaMIkqG6MPZJi0ISMZ7lKa4DCA
debug1: Host 'IP' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/pavlovdog/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/pavlovdog/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg rsa-sha2-512 blen 535
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to IP ([IP]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LC_NAME = ru_RU.UTF-8
... Lot more 'Sending env' ...
```

Comment: what happens if you run a remote command `ssh pavlovdog@IP uptime` or the like?

Comment: @thrig whoa, it works! Returns `uptime` stats, but still can't connect as `ssh pavlovdog@IP`.

Comment: sounds like a shell problem; can you run `ssh -tt pavlovdog@IP /bin/sh` to try to get a shell?

Comment: It would be helpful to see the debug2 messages as well: `ssh -vv user@host...`